# "Port Forwarding" to a Shared Connection (open to larger Network)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, port-forwarding, wired-networking

**I have 2 servers, Server A and Server B.**

**TL;DR: I want Server A's ports; 1025, and 1026; to be forwarded to Server B's ports; 1025, and 1026.**

I want to open 2 ports on Server B; 1025, and 1026; to the larger network, Server B's using Server A's (shared) connection to the larger network. Server A's connection is shared via a regular CAT5e cable. Server A's network connection is on wlan0 and wlan1.

**I'm running Lubuntu 14.04 LTS on both servers.**

Comment: What kind of connection does Server B have to Server A?  Bridged interfaces?  NAT firewall?  Proxy?

Comment: @trpt4him "Shared" connection, I went into the network icon, and clicked "Edit Connections" then in IPv4 settings I set it to shared.